# Displaying objects of several users in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am coding network site and it has "Follow/Unfollow" function. When user follows X,Y users, there are following tab in the nav bar. There should be displayed all the posts of X,Y users the user has followed.

Here is the `view` function:

```
def following(request):
    currentUser = request.user
    users = currentUser.following.all() #Getting all the users the currentUser is followed to
    context = {"posts": postsOfFollowedUsers}
    return render(request, "network/following.html", context)
```

How do I display all the posts related to several users?